# How to return Boolean instead of returning void from a token validity function in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am checking the JWT validation using the following code in Java. This is working fine and also getting exception if the token is invalid. But, I just need to return true/false, depending on the validity of the JWT. How can I achieve that?

```
public void validateToken(final String token) {
    Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getSignKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token);
  }
```

Comment: `try { /*jwt validation code*/ return true;} catch (YourJwtValidationException e) { return false; }` ?

Answer (score 1):

just use the try catch, return true in try block, and return false in catch block